# Expire exam content on moving to another tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

I have an online exam app but I need to prevent cheating how I could set a feature to my app expire content of exam when student goes to another tab please any Idea and suggestion

Comment: Check jQuery `unload()` function https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: You can't, not reliably at least: Any solution that relies on the client can be manipulated by the client.

Comment: "Ah, you don't let me switch to other windows during the exam? That's OK, I'll just use my cell phone." - There's really no way to do this reliably without having a completely controlled environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if a tab or window is active by attaching a blur / focus event listener to window.

in jQuery it would be

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    //do something
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    //do something
});
```